# 3D-Plot of a list of complex numbers and a list of real numbers

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, code-request

I'm a newcomer to Mathematica, and I'm having trouble with the following question.

Say we have a list of complex numbers `list1` and a list of real numbers `list2` (with the same amount of elements). I want to produce a 3D plot where `list1` is plotted in the complex plane (can consider it as the $\mathrm{xy}$-plane) against `list2` plotted in the $\mathrm{z}$-axis (with a point in `list1` in the $\mathrm{xy}$-plane, associated to the respective point in `list2` in the $\mathrm{z}$-axis). How would I be able to do this? I was thinking of using `ListPlot3D` but I'm not sure on how to apply it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Have you tried `Re` and `Im`?

Comment: As in extracting `Re`, `Im` of `list1` and then plotting it with `list2` using `ListPlot3D`?

Comment: @hoyast, sounds like a plan.

Comment: @hoyast Try to find out why you can apply `Re` and `Im` on lists (lookup `Listable`) and how easily you can re-arrange columns and rows if you think about it as *transposing* a matrix (or a tensor in general). Try `ListPlot3D[Transpose[{Re[list1], Im[list1], list2}]]`, but don't just use it. Understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to get an answer on record, so I will present an example that demonstrates the answers given in the comments to the question.

I start by generating some random data

```
SeedRandom[42];
xy = RandomComplex[{0., 10. + 10. I}, 6]
z = RandomReal[10., 6]
```

> ```
> {4.25905 + 2.96848 I, 3.91023 + 2.06408 I, 3.47069 + 3.2517 I, 
>  4.53741 + 9.73325 I, 5.55963 + 2.58796 I, 2.89169 + 5.50582 I}
>
> {7.17287, 7.54353, 8.60349, 9.96966, 7.39226, 0.383646}
> ```

Then, making use of the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute of `Re` and `Im`, the 3D coordinates are given by

```
 xyz = Transpose[{Re[xy], Im[xy], z}]
```

> ```
> {{4.25905, 2.96848, 7.17287}, {3.91023, 2.06408, 7.54353}, 
>  {3.47069, 3.2517, 8.60349}, {4.53741, 9.73325, 9.96966}, 
>  {5.55963, 2.58796, 7.39226}, {2.89169, 5.50582, 0.383646}}
> ```

and can be visualized by

```
ListPlot3D[xyz, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: plot]